# Function foreach is only returning last array

Tags: php, function, foreach

I have this being put into a table listing and what it does is the first function populates the first three rows and then the second function populates the 4th row based on the match of the first function.

```
public function function1($start = 0, $max = 10, $use_result = false) {

    $sql = 'SELECT itemnum, descrip FROM TABLENAME
                WHERE itemnum LIKE "__-_____"
                AND cms_item_id IS NULL
                ORDER BY itemnum ASC
                LIMIT ' . (int)$start . ',' . (int)$max .'';
    $result = $this->registry->db->query($sql);

    $return = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $return[] = $row;
    }
    return $return;
}

/**
 * Get matches
 * @return array
 */
public function function2(){
    $product = $this->getList();
    foreach($product as $key) {
        $sku = $key['itemnum'];
        list(, $sku) = explode("-", $sku);
            }

    $sql = 'SELECT product_sku, long_name
    FROM TABLENAME
        WHERE product_sku = "' . $sku . '"';
    $result = $this->registry->db->query($sql);
    $return = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $return[] = $row;
        }
    return $return;
}
```

What is happening is the 3 rows are returning fine. But the 4th row is only returning the last $sku not anything matching. I know the foreach loop is being overwriting each time and the final one is being put into the variable $sku...but how else could I do this to get what I need?

Comment: `foreach` is dependent on `$product = $this->getList();` whish is not included in your code

Comment: @Baba I suspect `function1` is `getList`.

Comment: yes sorry I tried to remove things that I consider private information..and forgot that haha.. but yes All functions and table names are correct on my side just the above mentioned issue..thanks!

Comment: What is the value of $sku before putting in into the query? ( in function2)

Comment: the value is the last looped item. you can see I have a start of zero and max of 10. that is how many rows appear on the table. So the 10th row is the one that's repeating through 1-9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an array of all the SKUs, and use `IN` instead of `=` to match them.

```
public function function2(){
    $product = $this->getList();
    $skus = array();
    foreach($product as $key) {
        $sku = $key['itemnum'];
        list(, $sku) = explode("-", $sku);
        $skus[] = $sku;
    }
    $sku_string = implode(', ', array_map(function($x) {return "'$x'"; }, $skus));
    $sql = 'SELECT product_sku, long_name
            FROM TABLENAME
            WHERE product_sku IN (". $sku_string .")';
    $result = $this->registry->db->query($sql);
    $return = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $return[] = $row;
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Perhaps a better solution would be to combine your queries into one:

```
SELECT itemnum, descrip, long_name
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.product_sku = substring_index(itemnum, '-', -1)
WHERE itemnum LIKE "__-_____"
AND cms_item_id IS NULL
ORDER BY itemnum ASC
LIMIT ' . (int)$start . ',' . (int)$max
```

Comment: Doesnt seem to be working. You had a missing ) on the implode but dumping $sku_string before the while loop does produce the needed result. However, dumping it inside the while loop produces nothing. I have that while loop set up in a template that is using a foreach smarty loop {    {foreach $match as $row}
     {$row.product_sku} | {$row.long_name}
    {/foreach}}

Comment: and that is coming off the main "file" $this->smarty->assign('match', $match);....$match = $this->display->getProductMatch();

Comment: It's hard to tell what's right without more context, that's the problem with sanitizing your problem like this. Maybe you need to nest the query and its `while` loop inside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: I don't know Smarty, so I can't help you there.

Comment: Yeah I understand. What is happening is I have three rows. lets say product, product name and a link button the product is a number sku based on XX-XXXXX format on the first function (thats where the explode comes in) on the second function its only one row from another table that could possible hold that same product number only in the format of XXXXX (the last five numbers after the dash) So what is happening is its pulling that product number from the one table and linking it with the product number from the other table and then putting them into a table style list to be able to "Link"

Comment: smarty is nothing more then a template engine I can handle that part I was just trying to show the whole scope of the situation I cant understand why such a easy problem is so hard for me lol

Comment: Are you just trying to add the long name of each item to the corresponding row in `$product`?

Comment: kinda of the long_name is basically the description of the product_sku. But the product_sku is whats needing to match with itemnum..thats why itemnum is coming from the first function and thats why it gets exploded and thrown into the query WHERE product_sku = matching sku

Comment: Can do you an output of the $skus-array or $sku_string ? I think it would be easier to solve the problem then (do it in your original question)

Comment: this is the var_dump for sku_string..if thats what you were asking string(88) "'8JY66', '8WNAW', 'RKIAG', 'WSVGS', 'T8XZ1', 'MG0MA', '2K0ZS', 'BNPQK', 'BNPQK', 'BNPQK'"

Comment: Do a single SQL-statement and JOIN tables in function getList() instead as @Barmar suggests.

Comment: How could I use JOIN? Doesnt that only show results that match? I am not sure how to run a sql statement explode it and run it through antoher query in one function?

Comment: See the query I just added that shows how to join your two tables based on SKU.

Comment: ok I was able to run the query in workbench but i still get Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Comment: then you had a syntax error in the query in PHP, look at `mysql_error()`.

Comment: GOT IT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!...JUST HAD TO FIX THE QUOTES!...YOU GUYS ARE AMAZING THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR THE HELP!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public function function2(){
    $product = $this->getList();

    $sku = array();               //Make an empty $sku array
    foreach($product as &$key) {
        $sku = $key['itemnum'];
        list(, $sku) = explode("-", $sku);
        $key['sku'] = $sku;
        $skus[] = $sku;
    }
    $selectValues = implode(',', $skus);

    $sql = "SELECT product_sku, long_name FROM TABLENAME WHERE product_sku IN($selectValues)";
    $result = $this->registry->db->query($sql);
    $return = array();

    $long_names = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $long_names[$row['product_sku']] = $row['long_name'];
    }

    foreach ($product as &$key) {
        $key['long_name'] = $long_names[$key['sku']];
    }
    return $product;
}
```

Comment: Error: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object...I need that explode in there also thats how the match is made

Comment: How does the $sql look like in this function? (If you echo it)

Comment: It's not quoting the SKUs, so it's probably getting a syntax error.

Comment: Are the skus numeric? or strings? What is the output of the $sku-array?

Comment: This answer is basically trying the same approach as my answer. But you seem to have left out the part of the original code that splits the item number at `-` to get the SKU.

Comment: @Barmar - hm yes I see that know. I apologize. I will let you move on with your answer because you were first :-)

Comment: Best would probably be to do it all in the query in `getList()`, using a `JOIN`.

Comment: See updated answer that merges the long names into `$product`.